# playwright-dotnet: how to get an element with multiple css classes

Tags: c#, playwright-sharp

in the example below how do I get the url of the image with playwright-dotnet?

```
<div class="v-image__image v-image__image--contain" 
style="background-image: url("https://example.com/myimage.jpg"); 
background-position: right center;"></div>
```

I tried to select the div with await `page.InnerHTMLAsync("div.v-image__image v-image__image--contain");` to no avail.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The right CSS selector for that is `DIV.v-image__image.v-image__image--contain`

```
const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({ headless: false });
let page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setContent(`
<div class="v-image__image v-image__image--contain" 
style='background-image: url("https://example.com/myimage.jpg"); 
background-position: right center;'></div>
`);

const el = await page.$("DIV.v-image__image.v-image__image--contain");
const styleProperty = await el.getProperty("style");
const style = await styleProperty.jsonValue();
console.log(style.backgroundImage);
await browser.close();
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work: it throws an exception because it doesn't find the selector.

Comment: @JMN-RTTB it does work. Example added.

Comment: Your answer use JavaScript, but I use the C# version of Playwright.